# How to update my array and return in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter model function that needs to return array like this...

```
{"speakers":[{
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Jack",
        "events":{
              "id":"1"
              "name":"event1",
             },
             {
              "id":"2"
              "name":"event2",
             },
        "status":"Active",
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Tom",
        "events":{
              "id":"3"
              "name":"event3",
             },
        "status":"Active",
    },
        {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"Maria",
        "events":{
              "id":"1"
              "name":"event1",
             },
        "status":"Active",
    }]
}
```

This is my code:

```
function speakers()
    {
        $speakers=$this->db->get("speakers_tbl");
        $data = array();
        if($speakers->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach ($speakers->result_array() as $row)
            {
                $this->db->from('events_tbl');
                $this->db->where('speaker_id', $row['id']);
                $final = $this->db->get()->result_array();             
                $data[] = array_merge($row, $final);         
            }
            return $data;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is a JSON representation of your data.

Change:

`return $data;`

for

`return json_encode($data);`

Now, if you also want an indented display such as your example, when outputting to the browser, you may use `print "<pre>".print_r($data,true)."</pre>";`

Comment: that's not the issue... i have to print multiarray using that model function...